# getHeaders() to get source ip address

Tags: map, header

We are currently using a managed package UI .

Upon clicking of Account in service console , user is directed to the managed package UI and not any VF Page .

How can I get the value of UI using getHeaders()

```
 map<String, String> mapHeaders = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders();
```

and

```
 X-Salesforce-SIP
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below getheader() can return this.

```
host= ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
referer=ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().gete('Referer');
useragent=ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');
chipersuite=ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Chipersuite');
forward=ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-Forwarded-To');
salesforceip= ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP');
```

Header information details can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm#RequestHeadersSection)

Comment: Thanks Avijit . But is there any other way apart from get Header to get the ip address . I am not using VF Page

Comment: You can take help of trigger to do soql on login history